# mysql query locking everything up

Tags: mysql

A user has a query that locks up everything else in the database when it runs.
I ran a profile and it returns a lot of records but don't really know what to do with it.
Can someone possibly code this more efficiently?  It runs for quite a while.

```
SELECT

CLAIMS.LINE_GROUPING1

,CLAIMS.LOSS_DATE

,(CASE WHEN CLAIMS.POLICY_STATE=14 THEN 'IA'

WHEN CLAIMS.POLICY_STATE=12 THEN 'IL'

WHEN CLAIMS.POLICY_STATE=22 THEN 'MN'

WHEN CLAIMS.POLICY_STATE=26 THEN 'NE'

WHEN CLAIMS.POLICY_STATE=40 THEN 'SD'

WHEN CLAIMS.POLICY_STATE=48 THEN 'WI'

ELSE 'NA' END) AS POLICY_STATE

,CLAIMS.CLAIM_ZIPCODE

,CLAIMS.DIRECT_CASE_INC

,CLAIMS.OCC_CNT

,CLAIMS.DIRECT_CASE_INC*

(CASE WHEN CLAIMS.ACCIDENT_YEAR  IN(2013)

      THEN 1.00

  WHEN CLAIMS.LINE_GROUPING1='PERSONAL AUTO' AND CLAIMS.ACCIDENT_YEAR < 2013

      THEN COALESCE(COALESCE(TREND.TREND,AUTO_AVG.AVG_TREND),1.00)

  WHEN CLAIMS.LINE_GROUPING1='HOMEOWNERS' AND CLAIMS.ACCIDENT_YEAR BETWEEN 2007 AND (2013-1)

      THEN COALESCE(COALESCE(TREND.TREND,HOME_AVG.AVG_TREND),1.00)

  WHEN CLAIMS.LINE_GROUPING1='HOMEOWNERS' AND CLAIMS.ACCIDENT_YEAR =2006

      THEN COALESCE(COALESCE(TREND_HOME_2007.TREND,HOME_AVG_2007.AVG_TREND),1.00)

  ELSE 1.00 END)

AS EXP_ADJ_CASE_INC



 FROM mva.CLAIMS_STORM_LOSSES_TEMP AS CLAIMS

   LEFT OUTER JOIN mva.CLAIMS_Exposures_Trending AS TREND

 ON CLAIMS.LINE_GROUPING1 = TREND.LINE_GROUPING1

  AND CLAIMS.ACCIDENT_YEAR = TREND.ACCIDENT_YEAR

 AND CLAIMS.POLICY_STATE = TREND.STATE

AND CLAIMS.CLAIM_ZIPCODE = TREND.ZIPCODE

LEFT OUTER JOIN mva.CLAIMS_Exposures_Trending AS TREND_HOME_2007 #DONT HAVE A 2006 TREND FACTOR

ON CLAIMS.LINE_GROUPING1 = TREND_HOME_2007.LINE_GROUPING1

AND TREND_HOME_2007.ACCIDENT_YEAR=2007

AND CLAIMS.POLICY_STATE = TREND_HOME_2007.STATE

AND CLAIMS.CLAIM_ZIPCODE = TREND_HOME_2007.ZIPCODE  

LEFT OUTER JOIN mva.CLAIMS_Exposures_Auto_AVG_TREND AS AUTO_AVG

ON AUTO_AVG.ACCIDENT_YEAR = CLAIMS.ACCIDENT_YEAR

AND AUTO_AVG.STATE = CLAIMS.POLICY_STATE

LEFT OUTER JOIN mva.CLAIMS_Exposures_Home_AVG_TREND AS HOME_AVG

ON HOME_AVG.STATE = CLAIMS.POLICY_STATE

AND HOME_AVG.ACCIDENT_YEAR = CLAIMS.ACCIDENT_YEAR

LEFT OUTER JOIN mva.CLAIMS_Exposures_Home_AVG_TREND AS HOME_AVG_2007 #DONT HAVE A 2006   TREND FACTOR

ON HOME_AVG_2007.STATE = CLAIMS.POLICY_STATE

AND HOME_AVG_2007.ACCIDENT_YEAR = CLAIMS.ACCIDENT_YEAR

AND HOME_AVG_2007.ACCIDENT_YEAR=2007;
```

Comment: Without knowing what is in all those tables, with all those joins, and how much data it's gotta go through, it's really tough to examine why it's taking so long to run.

Comment: Some queries are just made to be run for a few seconds to minutes to even hours. While making sure it is efficiently queried, there is no guarantee that it will run in a few seconds. If you have large amounts of data, this is bound to happen. I worked on a bank a few years ago, and there are queries that just take hours to run.

Comment: Is this query being run by a user each time ad is? I would suggest a procedure would be the way to go for complex logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use InnoDB database engine
2. Use Explain query to check if indexes are used. Proper indexes would speed the query up a lot, so it wouldn't lock for a long time.